# EF creating procedures using ExecuteStoreCommand (running bulk scripts)

Tags: sql-server, entity-framework

```
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
-- =============================================
-- USP_TEST_SELECT
-- =============================================
IF EXISTS (SELECT name FROM sysobjects WHERE name = 'usp_test_select' AND type = 'P')
    DROP PROCEDURE usp_test_select
GO
CREATE PROCEDURE usp_test_select
    @id         int 
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;
    SELECT * FROM MY_TABLE mt WHERE mt.id = @id
END
GO
-- **********************************************
```

I read this script from a textfile and would like to run it using EF `.ExecuteStoreCommand` (or any other execute method in EF).

An exception is thrown :

> *System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException (0x80131904): Incorrect syntax near
>   'GO'.
>
>   'CREATE/ALTER PROCEDURE' must be the first statement in a query batch.*

The scripts (text file) which I am running is generated by SQL Server Management Studio and runs with success if executed there.

Comment: `GO` is not a valid `T-SQL` statement, it is used only by SQL Management studio. Change your code to use dynamic create sql `If exists (condition) then exec('create procedre..')`

Comment: Thanks.. that was obvious I guess, just had my thoughts somewhere else. Thanks again! If you add it as an answer I'll accept it :)

Comment: i posted my comment as answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`GO` is not a valid `T-SQL statement`, it is used only by SQL Management studio. Change your code to use dynamic create sql 
Ex:

```
If exists (condition) then exec('create procedre..')
```